# Which is faster in a tight loop ? [swich-cast, if-else, goto-label]

Tags: c++, performance, if-statement, switch-statement, goto

I have a function: `f(param)`, which does a single calculation based on input (`param`). This function supposed to be called something around 1 million (maximum) in a tight loop:

```cpp
for (std::uint_fast64_t i = 0; i < 1'000'000; ++i) {
  f (param);
}
```

#### *First Question*:

My (first) question is what is the most effective way to write the condition section (to what to do based on `param`) of the `f()` function. I tried some options that I know:

### `if-else if`:

```cpp
static int f_3(int const param) {
  if (A::_1 == param) {
    return A::_1 * param;
  } else if (A::_2 == param) {
    return A::_2 * param;
  } // ... 
}
```

### `switch-case`:

```cpp
static int f(int const param) {
  switch (param) {
    case A::_1:
      return param * A::_1;
    // ...
  }
}
```

### `goto-label`:

```cpp
static int f_2(int const param) {
  void constexpr* const  _table[] = {
    && L1, // ... 
  };

  goto* _table[param];

L1:
  return A::_1 * param;
// ...
}
```

And I benchmarked it:

- [The complete code.](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mg-ramezani/65fffe0d7e401f6a9d617497d064b3b2/raw/0e8f04278ce7a84a512a4d3c0191de234dc6cf60/test_2.cpp)
- **Compiler**: *g++ (GCC) 10.2.0*
- **Compiler options**: *-O3 -std=c++17 -lboost_timer*
- **OS**: *ArchLinux 5.10.8-arch1-1*

```cpp
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  using ufast_t = std::uint_fast64_t;

  ufast_t constexpr n = 1'000'000'000ULL;
  ufast_t sum = 0;

  {
    std::cout << "switch-case :";
    boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer _f;
    for (ufast_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      sum += f(argc);
    }
  }
  std::cout << "---------------------------" << std::endl;
  {
    std::cout << "goto        :";
    boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer _f2;
    for (ufast_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      sum += f_2(argc);
    }
  }
  std::cout << "---------------------------" << std::endl;
  {
    std::cout << "if-elseif   :";
    boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer _f3;
    for (ufast_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      sum += f_3(argc);
    }
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;

  return sum;
}
```

But it has (i think) a strange output:

```sh
 > ./a.out 1 2 3 4 5 6
switch-case : 1.056976s wall, 1.050000s user + 0.000000s system = 1.050000s CPU (99.3%)
---------------------------
goto        : 0.000001s wall, 0.000000s user + 0.000000s system = 0.000000s CPU (n/a%)
---------------------------
if-elseif   : 0.645751s wall, 0.640000s user + 0.000000s system = 0.640000s CPU (99.1%)

 > echo $?
0
```

So is there any (effective) way to do that? or I just have those options in my hand and I have to select one of them based on some benchmarks?

#### *Second Question*:

Why `goto` in the above benchmark doesn't have any overhead? It's Undefined behavior code? or somehow the compiler removes their loops in the optimization stage?

Comment: Doesn't this code return `param * param` in every case? (And cause undefined behaviour if no `A::_X` matches `param`)

Comment: @churill, I return `A::_x * param` just for a test (to show is there only one simple calculation), and again just for the test, I don't check the input range because in every test I set `param` with a random number between the valid range.

Comment: Is the `param` the same for all calls? If so, I would move the check out of the loop.

Comment: There are more weaknesses in your code: `sum = + f(argc);`??? Should this have been `sum += ...`? (If the compiler is clever enough it will reduce it to one iteration - because of detecting missing side effects.) In general, in such case, I would compare the asm output on Compiler Explorer to get an impression. (This is also good to check what is really performed at run-time. The compilers are meanwhile also good in pre-computing things at compile time.)

Comment: @n314159, Yes, It's the same for all calls. It specifies before starting the loop (in the production code).

Comment: @GhasemRamezani Ok, but that might influence the result of your timing, if the compiler is clever enough. Also, if `A` contains only contiguous values you can consider a look up table. (if possible for the real calculation)

Comment: @Scheff, Oh, I sabotaged badly. Yes it should be `sum += f(argc);`. (I checked the assembly output in the compiler explorer but I don't understand it.)

Comment: Nothing is stopping the compiler from reordering the 3 loops to the end of the program, when you actually `return sum;`. Try printing `sum` after each loop. I would be very surprised if there was any difference between the 3 versions. Note that the compiler is very smart nowadays and can inline functions and sometimes eliminate loops entirely.

Comment: I would also include something, the compiler cannot know in any case, e.g. something assigned from input. Output of a result is recommendable as well (to prevent optimization due to missing side-effects). Of course, care to exclude I/O from time measurement. ;-)

Comment: @Scheff, I changed `sum =+ f(argc);` to `sum += ...`. (thank you)

Comment: compare the generated asm code. takes the guessing away

Comment: @rustyx, I print it out, and surprisedly all is the same. But why return value is `0`?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think, that the 3 different methods should differ that much from each other, since the compiler will probably recognize what you are doing and do the best thing. The most readable variant is the `switch`, but that is opinion based. It should also definitely emit a jump table as assembler, which should be the fastest option. But just trust the compiler for that.

It would be best to move the check out of the loop. I can imagine that the compiler will be able to recognize that param does not change and move the check out, itself, but that is much less certain. To make sure, you can do something like this:

```
template<A param>
auto foo() {
    // This function will be generated once for each enumerator of A that is included
    // in the switch below. In each variant the runtime code will not contain these
    // checks against param.
    if constexpr(param == A::_1) { 
    } else if constexpr(param == A::_2) {
    } ...
}

template<A param>
auto loop() {
    for(auto i = 0ul; i < 1'000'000; ++i) {
        foo<param>();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    switch(argc) {
        case A::_1: 
            loop<A::_1>();
            break; 
        ....
    }
}
```

Sadly, there is to my knowledge no nice way to switch on argc.

Comment: How it could be at compile-time, while its input value (in this case `param` template value parameter) is specified at run time?

Comment: `argc` is checked at runtime, but we then switch on it and choose the appropiate code path. From this point on, we have `param` as a compile time value and hence can get all checks against done at compile time. I realise that my comment is  not that clear I will edit that.